# Why does this simple WPF ListView sample produce text which extends outside the Border?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have tried to distill this as best as possible.  Here is XAML for a simple ListView which contains a single item, templated with a single-row Grid enclosed by a Border:

```xml
        <ListView>
            <ListView.Items>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="First"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text=""/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Second"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView.Items>
        </ListView>
```

For some reason, the text extends outside the Border, which I'd never expect:

[image: For some reason, the text extends outside the Border, which I'd never expect]

If I set the ColumnDefinitions to have Width="Auto", it displays as I'd expect, but I'd still like to know why it behaves this way since I'll undoubtedly encounter this issue in the future.

Comment: Besides that it's really strange, why do you think you will encounter this issue in the future? Just use a [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview.view?view=netframework-4.7.2) with three GridViewColumns in the ListView.

Comment: No, I'm explicitly avoiding a GridView because a GridView introduced tons of problems that I'm now trying to avoid.  This is a distilled sample which looks like a perfect candidate for a GridView, but only because it's a distilled sample.

I'd encounter this issue in the future because I create lots of Grids and Borders and such.  And if I just rely on luck or solutions which just-so-happen-to-work-but-I-don't-know-why, then undoubtedly I'll keep hitting this.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve: content aligned left (from `ListBoxItem` template) but it's child is a `Grid` with `*` columns.... What is the desired behavior?

Comment: I just copied your XAML into a User control in VS 2017, it looks as expected to me. How did you make your screenshot?

Comment: @XAMeLi If you take a look at the black border, you'll see that the letters 'n' and 'd' of the word "Second" flow outside of it.  I would like them to remain inside of it.  Another way of stating this is: I'd like the content enclosed by a Border tag to be enclosed by the resulting border.

Comment: @JimFoye I use Alt+PrintScreen.  The screenshot exactly resembles the application window.  I notice that as I type various characters, the spacing changes, sometimes correcting itself and sometimes looking worse.  For example, if the empty string in the middle column is changed to something longer, it often makes everything line up properly.

Comment: If you switch back to an older framework version (e.g. 4.6.2) , the issue disappears, but the columns aren't equally sized, which is also wrong. You should write a bug report to Microsoft.